# Syntax highlighting is available only when new .sh and .py files are created in centos7

Tags: linux, vim

It has been found that using VIM to create `.py` and `.sh` files is highlighted, and opening system configuration files such as `/etc/psswd`, `/etc/.vimrc` is highlighted, but for example, new `123.txt` files or 123files cannot be highlighted.

I ensure that I have I can make sure that I have not made any special settings for specific files, and vim should be able to highlight under any circumstances.

The `vimrc`'s code is as below.

```
set bs=indent,eol,start         " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
"set ai                 " always set autoindenting on
"set backup             " keep a backup file
set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more
                        " than 50 lines of registers
set history=50          " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler               " show the cursor position all the time

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
if has("autocmd")
  augroup redhat
  autocmd!
  " In text files, always limit the width of text to 78 characters
  " autocmd BufRead *.txt set tw=78
  " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
  autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
  \ endif
  " don't write swapfile on most commonly used directories for NFS mounts or USB sticks
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre /media/*,/run/media/*,/mnt/* set directory=~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
  " start with spec file template
  autocmd BufNewFile *.spec 0r /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/template.spec
  augroup END
endif

if has("cscope") && filereadable("/usr/bin/cscope")
   set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
   set csto=0
   set cst
   set nocsverb
   " add any database in current directory
   if filereadable("cscope.out")
      cs add $PWD/cscope.out
   " else add database pointed to by environment
   elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
      cs add $CSCOPE_DB
   endif
   set csverb
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

filetype plugin on

if &term=="xterm"
     set t_Co=8
     set t_Sb=^[[4%dm
     set t_Sf=^[[3%dm
endif

" Don't wake up system with blinking cursor:
" http://www.linuxpowertop.org/known.php
```

Comment: Text files have no inherent structure or syntax, so what kind of syntax highlighting do you expect in a `*.txt` file? Also, you are supposed to put *your* own settings in *your* own `vimrc`, in *your* own $HOME.

Comment: Hello, expert.
I want to be able to achieve syntax highlighting in any file, such as echo, grammar, syntax, bind, etc.
The .vimrc file for my home directory is as follows:
Set nu.

Syntax on.

Set shiftwidth=4.

Set softtabstop=4.

Set tabstop=4.

Set expandtab

Comment: You can't have syntax highlighting when there is no syntax to highlight. You have to somehow give your editor a hint as to what syntax to expect in your file: file extension, modeline, etc. Your question is too vague. What do you do, exactly? What do you expect? What do you get instead? For example: "I do <exact command> in Vim and I expect <exact outcome> but I get <exact undesired outcome> instead."

Comment: Hello, expert.Thank you for your help. I got the meaning. At first, I thought that syntax highlighting should be highlighted in all types of files, which is a problem of my understanding, so my problem has been solved.What I'm talking about should be a normal phenomenon. I have another question 
I would also like to ask a question about the reading order of vimrc(That is, the configuration file shown in vim-- version).
Thank you for your help. I will adopt your answer.

Comment: You can ask your question about reading order separately.